# GRASS GIS using a loop with r.neighbors command

Tags: grass-gis, loop

I'd like to do a **trend analysis with ndvi data** from 1982 til 2005. I am using the `r.neighbors` command to get first the spatial variance (then I would use `r.series` method=slope to get the actual trend) and in order to speed things up I'd like to do it using a loop... however it is not running :(
Here is my code... can someone help me?

```
for a in 
  1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 
  1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 ; do

  for i in 311 ; do
    r.neighbors
      input=AVHRR_NDVI_$aDOY$i
      output=AVHRR_NDVI_$aDOY$i.sp.var
      method=variance
      size=5
     echo "loop ends" ;
   done ;
 done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sequence, you can use "seq" and variables with trailing characters need to be defined with curly braces:

```
for a in `seq 1982 2005` ; do
    for i in 311 ; do
        r.neighbors input=AVHRR_NDVI_${a}DOY$i output=AVHRR_NDVI_${a}DOY$i.sp.var method=variance size=5
    done
done
```

Comment: i got it,see:   for i in 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 ; do
for a in 356 ; do
r.neighbors input=AVHRR_NDVI_"$i"DOY$a output=AVHRR_NDVI_"$i"DOY$a.sp.var method=variance size=5 --o;
echo "loop ends" ; done ; done. Just needed to enter quotationmarks after $i so that its not confused with DOY whihc is not a variable in this case.but thanks anyways.

Comment: So, everything solved?

Comment: uuuuuuuuuuuuh yes

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 ; do 
   for i in 311 ; do 
          r.neighbors input=AVHRR_NDVI_$aDOY$i output=AVHRR_NDVI_$aDOY$i.sp.var method=variance size=5 
          echo "loop ends" ; 
     done ; 
done
```

I would say, you are missing ";" before last "echo"

Comment: hmm no it still does not work, but thanks anyways.

Comment: hmm no it still does not work, but thanks anyways. for whatever reason it is complaining "AVHRR_NDVI_311: command not found...I dont get why it is not taken the values for a.....

Comment: You need to use curly braces for variables which are followed by a string: e.g. AVHRR_NDVI_$aDOY$i --> AVHRR_NDVI_${a}DOY$i. Then it will work.

Comment: @Jachym: I'll take liberty to repost your post :)